# h2 markup error inside JQuery read more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hide text and add “read more” links using jQuery.
Have a proplem to give the middle text a h2 markup.
What does I have to change to get it to work?

I use a code from code-tricks.
Here is a link to the orginal code snippets: 
http://code-tricks.com/jquery-read-more-less-example/#demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 100;
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Show more >";
  var lesstext = "Show less";


  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}
.morelink {
  display: block;
}
.productdescription {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.productdescription h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}
.productdescription strong {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.productdescription ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  padding: 24px 0px 0px 15px;
}
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}
.morelink {
  display: block;
}
.morelink {
  color: #4285f4;
  display: inline-block;
}
.morelink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.less {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="productdescription more">
<strong>Produktdetails</strong> 
  
Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. 
  
  
  
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by having a problem setting h2 markup, what have you tried so far?

Comment: It might be noteworthy that wrapping `h2` or `ul` in a span is only legal in HTML 5.

Comment: How do you make sure your JS function doesn't "cut" the html in the middle of a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Put that text inside a tag with an id:

```
<div id="forTheH2">
Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. Change this text to a headline h2. 

</div>
```

and then, just use jQuery .html()

```
$("#forTheH2").html("<h2>Change this text... </h2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach to solve the hide/show more text functionality which requires no Javascript. It will, though, require some clever styling/positioning to look like you want it to look. I've created a small demonstration using a checkbox for switching purposes, making use of the `:checked` css 3 pseudo selector.

```
    #more {
  display: none;
}
label {
  float: right;
}
.morecontent {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#more:checked ~ .morecontent {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
label+label {
  display: none;
}
#more:checked + label {
  display: none;
}
#more:checked + label + label {
  display: inline;
}
.morecontainer {
  width: 250px;
}
.morecontent p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
<div class="morecontainer">

  <input type="checkbox" id="more" />
  <label for="more">...more</label>
  <label for="more">...less</label>
  <div class="morecontent">
    <p>This is the container that is supposed to have that more text functionality applied to it.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>This solution requires no Javascript.</li>
      <li>You can use a tiny little bit of JS for pure animation purposes.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since I had some issues with the inline code editor from stackoverflow, I've additionaly created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jch69nqv/